# How do I force all ul elements to stay in one line?

Tags: html, css

I'm quite frustrated as I am attempting to make a hotbar, however the ul elements sometimes split into rows.

Here's an image of the outcome -https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSIDY.jpg

If anyone could please let me know what I can do to solve this, I'd be very thankful.

Code is below ---

```css
.nav a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image:url("");
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
}

.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/3ay8hjS.jpg');
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.learn-more {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}

.neighborhoood-guides {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb
}









 
.clearfix:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
 
/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#fff;
}
 
.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
 
.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
 
.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:black;
}
 
.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:dodgerblue;
}
 
.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}
 
/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;
    
}
 
.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    
}
 
.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#fff;
}
 
/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}
 
.sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#fff;
}
 
.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
}
 
.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight:bold
}
 
.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Destinations <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Airlines</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hotels</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a></li>
            <li>
           <li><a href="#">Cruiselines</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weddings & Honeymoons</a></li>
            <li>
                
                <a href="#">Useful Information <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
 
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Travel Insurance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                </ul>
            
            </nav>
        
</div>       
        

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Find the vacation you deserve.</h1>
        <p>--- Insert mouth-watering description here ---</p>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class ="neighborhood-guides">
    <div class ="container">
    <h2> Neighborhood Guides </h2>
    <p> Not sure where to stay? We've created neighborhood guides for cities all around the world.</p>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="http://goo.gl/0sX3jq">
    </div>
    <div class="Thumbnail">
    <img src="http://goo.gl/an2HXY">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="Thumbnail">
   <img src="http://goo.gl/Av1pac">
   </div>
   <div class="Thumbnail">
   <img src="http://goo.gl/vw43v1">
   </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="Thumbnail">
    <image src="http://goo.gl/0Kd7UO">
    </div>
    </div>
    
 

    <div class="learn-more">
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>Travel</h3>
   <p>From apartments and rooms to treehouses and boats: stay in unique spaces in 192 countries.</p>
   <p><a href="#"></a></p>
       </div>
    <div class ="col-md-4">
   <h3>Host</h3>
   <p></p>
   <p><a href="#"></a></p>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-4">
   <h3>Trust and Safety</h3>
   <p></p>
   <p><a href="#"></a></p>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reduce your padding in your menu ul li a to 10px 20px

```
.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;

}
```

and they'll stay on the same line

Answer (score 0):

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k8o2ce0/)

```
.menu > ul > li > a {
padding:10px 10px;
display:inline-block;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
text-transform:uppercase;
font-weight:bold;
}
```